# How can we create a metaclass so as to customize the behavior of `__call__()` for types instantiated from the meta-class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, new-operator, metaclass

Consider the following code:

```py
class Mehta(type):
    pass

class Klass(metaclass = Mehta):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return "LIZZY THE LIZARD"

instance = Klass(1, 2, 3)
print(instance)
print(instance())

<__main__.Klass object at 0x0000014546957F40>
LIZZY THE LIZARD
```

How can we write a metaclass in python so that `Klass(1, 2, 3)` behaves more like:

```py
Klass(1, 2, 3).__call__()
```

### One of Many Potential Motivations:

I often want to split a function into two halves:

#### **HALF ONE**

Does a lot of error checking on the function inputs.

For example, we might check that a string parameter `s` really does contain letters only.

```py
import string

def funky_the_function(s:str):
    if len(s) != sum(1 if ch in string.ascii_letters else 0 for ch in s):
        raise ValueError('`s` must contain only letters')

funky_the_function("abcde")
funky_the_function("hello world")
```

We might check that an input parameter named `height` really is instantiated from a class having an operator `+` defined (`__add__()`)

```py
assert(hasattr(height, "__add__"))
```

#### HALF TWO

The second "half" of our function begins executing the "meat" of our task immediately without sanitizing or checking function inputs.

#### Getting rid of the Double Paren-Paren

One of many ways to seperate error-checking from non-error checking is to write a class which has two pieces:

- `__init__()` does all of the error checking, sanitizes function inputs, and then stores them as member variables.
- `__call__()` performs the primary task, loading its inputs from stored member variables.

````py
import io

class truncate:
    """
        Example of Code Which Uses truncate:
        ```
            s = "\r<class\n 'builtin_function_or_method'>"
            s = truncate(s, 10)()
            print(s)
                    ```
                Examples of Inputs and Outputs:
                        truncate(s, 2)()   ==  \r
                        truncate(s, 4)()   ==  \r<c
                        truncate(s, 10)()  ==  \r<c [...]
                        truncate(s, 20)()  ==  \r<class\n 'bu [...]
                        truncate(s, 999)() ==  \r<class\n 'builtin_function_or_method'>
                    ```
                Other Notes:
                    Returns a modified copy of string input
                    Does not modify the original string
            """
    def __init__(self, x_stryng: str, x_leng: int) -> str:
        """
        This initializer mostly exists to sanitize function inputs
        """
        try:
            stryng = repr("".join(str(ch) for ch in x_stryng))[1:-1]
            leng = int(str(x_leng))
        except BaseException as exc:
            invalid_stryng =  str(x_stryng)
            invalid_stryng_truncated = repr(type(self)(invalid_stryng, 20)())

            invalid_x_leng = str(x_leng)
            invalid_x_leng_truncated = repr(type(self)(invalid_x_leng, 20)())

            strm = io.StringIO()
            print("Invalid Function Inputs", file=strm)
            print(type(self).__name__, "(",
                  invalid_stryng_truncated,
                  ", ",
                  invalid_x_leng_truncated, ")", sep="", file=strm)
            msg = strm.getvalue()

            raise ValueError(msg) from None

        self._stryng = stryng
        self._leng = leng

    def __call__(self) -> str:
        stryng = self._stryng
        leng = self._leng
        return (stryng[:leng - 6] + " [...]")[:min(len(stryng), leng)]
````

We end up with lots of redundant parentheses.

```py
new_string = truncate(old_string)() # extra `()` at the end  
parsed_phone = parse_phone_number(format_string, "303.191.9968")() # extra `()`
```

Comment: This really just sounds like a job for a function. If that function has a "check inputs" phase and a "use inputs" phase, that's fine. "My function has two phases" is not a good reason to use crazy metaclasses.

Comment: (Also, that `truncate` class is more likely to obfuscate errors than actually do anything useful with that `except BaseException` block.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll present the answer to make the proposed solution work, explain why it is a poor solution and present some alternatives.

### Use metaclass

```
class Mehta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args):
        instance = super().__call__(*args)
        return instance(*args)
```

`Klass()` will now invoke `Mehta.__call__` which contains the steps requested. i.e. instantiating an instance of `Klass` the normal way and returning the results of calling that instance.

This is unnecessarily complicated for the problem shown. `__init__` and `__call__` have be hijacked and then it used metaclasses in a round about way to invoke them. But a normal class can do what's needed...

### Use `__new__`

Considering that there's no need to keep an instance around, why create it in the first place?

```
class Truncate:
    def __new__(cls, user_string: str, length: int):
        try:
            return cls.formatted(
                cls.parsed_user_string(user_string),
                cls.parsed_length(length),
            )
        except:
            # debug dump

    @staticmethod
    def parsed_user_string(user_string: str):
        # do stuff
        return user_string

    @staticmethod
    def parsed_length(length: int):
        # do stuff
        return length

    @staticmethod
    def formatted(user_string, length):
        # do stuff
        return 'the answer'
```

This may come in useful if you have multiple commands and they have things in common like where to dump debug too. But as it stands, even this is unnecessarily complicated for the problem shown. It's just a bunch of static functions...

### Use Functions

```
def _parsed_user_string(user_string: str):
    # do stuff
    return user_string

def _parsed_length(length: int):
    # do stuff
    return length

def _formatted(user_string, length):
    # do stuff
    return 'the answer'

def truncate(user_string: str, length: int):
    try:
        return _formatted(
            _parsed_user_string(user_string),
            _parsed_length(length),
        )
    except:
        # debug dump
```